# establish connection between mySQL database and android app

Tags: php, android, mysql

i have been trying to connect to my database in mySQL database.with this code

```
  Button btn_signup = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btn_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerProcess();
```

so that when my signup button is clicked it will use this code

```
 private void registerProcess(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

to connect to my database, but when clicked it displays "failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1:80".i defined my BASE_URL in my Constants.java like this

```
    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/android_login_example/";
```

Comment: You'll need a back-end [API of some sort](http://esbenp.github.io/2016/04/11/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-1/).

Answer (score 1):

`localhost` almost always refers to the machine running the application. In this case, that would be your phone. While it's possible that you have a MySQL DB running as an Android application, it seems more likely that you need to change the host value of the DB connection string.